# “Enemy” in German

Tags: difference, noun, vocabulary

I have translated *enemy* into German. There are more translations for that:

> Feind m, Erzrivale m, Erzfeind m, Todfeind m

I am studying a difference between them.

From DWDS:

> Feind = jmd., dessen (persönliches) Verhältnis zu einer bestimmten anderen Person durch Feindschaft bestimmt ist, oder: jmd., dessen Verhalten den Interessen einer bestimmten Gruppe von Menschen zuwiderläuft, der für diese Gruppe eine Bedrohung darstellt
>
> Erzrivale = {no entry}
>
> Erzfeind = {no entry}
>
> Todfeind = unversöhnlicher Gegner, hasserfüllter Feind

Which one of them refers to an enemy in war?

What is a difference between them?

Hypothesis: *Todfeind* refers to mortal enemy or deadly enemy. *Erzrivale* is a long term enemy, *Feind* can means a short term enemy.

Comment: Hypothese stimmt.

Comment: Also _Gegner, Gegenüber, Gegenspieler, Gegenseite, Kontrahent, Widersacher_ ‘opponent’, but usually just _Feind_, especially in war, except that current diplomatic or military jargon may prefer a fuzzier, possibly dehumanized term, e.g. _Ziel_ ‘target’, _Aggressor_ or some acronym.

Answer (score 2):

**Feind** - enemy (personal or during war)

**Erzfeind** - long-term, worst enemy (usually meant in a personal context)

**Rivale** - rival, opponent

**Erzrivale** - long-term, worst rival

If you do not know the meaning of 'rival' you should look it up.

Answer (score 2):

## Feind

This translation is the most generic one. In pretty much all cases where *enemy* is appropriate in English, *Feind* would be in German. Most importantly, this includes the rival of your current warfare.

> Wir werden dem Feind morgen bei Königgrätz begegnen, macht euch bereit für die Schlacht!

Two of the other words you found are direct modifications of *Feind* which only warrant a sub-entry in this post.

### Erzfeind

While not being able to back it up with sources, I think that the prefix *Erz-* originated from the word *Erzengel (arch angel).* I’m not sure about the development of *Erzengel* but it likely didn’t have anything to do with *Erz* but originated from a similar sounding word of a different language. And like the *Erzbischof (archbishop),* it was extended to other words being *very important.*

Thus, the *Erzfeind* is a very important enemy; one that has been an enemy for at least a generation, where various wars have been fought and where reconciliation seems very unlikely. Traditionally in German German usage, this applied to France (and pretty much only France). It is to be seen in the context of Bismarck’s anti-French alliances and the German-French war of 1870/1 plus the two World Wars (which each had a notable anti-French component).

If you wanted, you could translate it as *arch enemy* into English. I would be cautious about using it in German.

### Todfeind

This is an enemy that you hate so much, you would fight him to either of your deaths. The compound part *Tod-,* meaning *death,* signifies that. Like *mortal enemy,* you can consider it a stronger form of *Feind.*

> *X* ist nur mein Feind. Aber *Y* mag ich so wenig, ich würde ihn *Todfeind* nennen!

## Rivale

This is the root that forms most of the meaning of *Erzrivale*, which was included in your list. Its meaning is well translated as *rival* into English: A person who crosses your path, with whom you have to measure your powers but not more. The key difference between *Feinden* and *Rivalen* is that the latter might sit down for a beer after a winner has been determined, while a losing *Feind* would use such a beer to stick a dagger into his opponent’s intestines.

Thus, *Rivale* is often found in sports contexts. But for example in manga translations, a *Rivale* can also be a love rival.

### Erzrivale

This one basically follows the same idea as *Erzfeind* only without the historic connotations *Erzfeind* has. It is a rival you keep measuring yourself against (but against whom you don’t have to hold serious grudges).

> Der Erzrivale des FC Schalke 04 ist Borussia Dortmund.

Comment: And because the post wouldn’t be complete without it: »Die Steigerung von *Feind* lautet: *Feind – Todfeind – Parteifreund.«*

Answer (score 0):

*Erzfeind* -> *arch enemy*. Not sure if English has *arch rival*.

But *Feind* usually is severe enough. Simple opponents are *Rivalen* or *Gegner*. *Feind* describing persons or groups is rarely used in German because there's not much distinction to *Erzfeind*. Exception is being a *Feind* to a concept.

> Der Feind des Kleinunternehmers: Das Amt.
>
> Fast-Food-Konsumenten sind Feinde des guten Geschmacks.
>
> Der Feind des Guten ist das Bessere.

Using *Feindschaft* in contrary to *Freundschaft* is common.

> Die beiden pflegten eine jahrelange Feindschaft.
>
> Die Umweltbewegung stand in Feindschaft zur Kernkraft.

Military uses *Feind* when the forces of the opponent party are meant as a whole. Plural *Feinde* is almost never used in military terms.

> Der Feind sammelt sich hinter dem Wald.
>
> Wir erwarten Feindberührung nicht vor dem Abend.

Todfeind is rarely used. Only if *Erzfeind* is still too mellow.

And then there's the idiomatic expression of *einander **spinne**feind sein*, which describes a typical Jersey Shore cat fight.